# Convert a long dataframe to a wide dataframe on python (pandas) using stack/unstack or groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a long data frame that looks like this, with two headers the first one with variables and the second with just the date in a wide format.

|  | company | price | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date |  |  |  |
| 1/1/11 | TSLA | 2 | 1 |
| 1/2/11 | TSLA | 2 | 1 |
| 1/1/11 | MSFT | 2 | 1 |
| 1/2/11 | MSFT | 2 | 1 |

I want to shift it to a long format:

|  | price |  | volume |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date | TSLA | MSFT | TSLA | MSFT |
| 1/1/11 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/2/11 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

If possible i want to use stack or unstack/ groupby to do this. Assuming that I have the long dataframe saved as df - how would i convert it to a pandas dataframe named wide?

Comment: ``df.pivot('date', 'company')``? the pandas docs are quire helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` to add `company` as the second level of the MultiIndex, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) `company` into columns:

```
df = df.set_index('company', append=True).unstack(level='company')
```

`df`:

```
        price      volume     
company  MSFT TSLA   MSFT TSLA
date                          
1/1/11      2    2      1    1
1/2/11      2    2      1    1
```

---

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': {'1/1/11': 'MSFT', '1/2/11': 'MSFT'},
                   'price': {'1/1/11': 2, '1/2/11': 2},
                   'volume': {'1/1/11': 1, '1/2/11': 1}})
```